# Un Objeto de un Arrays lo guardo en otro Arrays .Al cambiar un dato del objeto del segundo Arrays también se modfica en el Objeto del primer Arrays

Tags: java

[image: Resultado al ejecutar el programa.]

Un Objeto de un Arrays lo guardo en otro Arrays. Al cambiar un dato del objeto del segundo Arrays también se modifica en el Objeto del primer Arrays.

¿Por qué pasa esto si al meterlo en otro arrays es como si fueran objetos distintos, no?

No tendría que ser en el Array 1 Fran y en el Arrays 2 Paco?

```
package prueba;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Prueba {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
     Persona p = new Persona("Fran", "Garcia");
     Persona a = new Persona();
     Persona b = new Persona();
     a.agregarTabla1(p);
     
     b.agregarTabla2();
     
   
     b.informacion();
     
        
        
        
        
    }
    
}

package prueba;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Persona {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;

    static Persona tabla[] = new Persona[0];
    static Persona tabla2[] = new Persona[0];

    public Persona(String nombre, String apellido) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public Persona() {
    }

   

    void agregarTabla1(Persona p) {
        tabla = Arrays.copyOf(tabla, tabla.length + 1);
        tabla[tabla.length - 1] = p;
    }

    void agregarTabla2() {

        tabla2 = Arrays.copyOf(tabla2, tabla2.length + 1);
        tabla2[tabla2.length - 1] = tabla[0];
        tabla2[tabla2.length - 1].nombre = "Paco";

    }

    void informacion() {

        System.out.println(tabla[0].nombre);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(tabla2[0].nombre);
    }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Por favor [edit] tu pregunta y publica el código relevante,  mensajes de error y datos directamente como texto y [no imágenes de código, errores o datos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21). Encontrás más información en [ask].

Comment: ¿Por qué pasa esto si al meterlo en otro arrays es como si fueran objetos distintos, no? NO. justamente... creaste un objeto nuevo? no.. asignaste el mismo objeto a mas de un lugar.. si no creas un objeto nuevo, es basicamente el mismo objeto, apuntado desde otro lugar...

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios  , creo que ya lo entiendo . Tendría que crear un objeto nuevo y asignarles los mismos datos , pero no asignar el objeto en sí . Gracias

Comment: Exacto, puedes crear un objeto y copiar los valores, o directamente clonarlo, ahora bien, ten en cuenta que esto solo es cierto con objetos, los primitivos (int, boolean, etc) no se pasan por referencia (un puntero a la posición en la memoria) sino por valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En java, las variables de tipo objeto son *referencias* a los objetos, y no las instancias de objetos en sí. (A diferencia de las variables que contienen tipos de datos primitivos, como un entero)<sup>1</sup>.

Una referencia es un *apuntador* a la instancia del objeto, como una *liga* o *llave electrónica* que te lleva al objeto, que reside en cierta dirección de la memoria de la computadora.

Cuándo realizas una asignación entre variables a objetos, lo que se hace es una copia de dicha *liga* o *llave*, y entonces las dos almacenan una referencia al mismo objeto, pero no existen dos objetos realmente, sino que ambas *apuntan* al mismo objeto.

Dicho en otras palabras, nunca se hace una copia o se crea otra instancia del objeto, solamente se copian las referencias al mismo.

Se puede ver en un ejemplo más sencillo, asumiendo una clase `Persona` similar a la que nos muestras:

```
Persona persona1 = new Persona("Fran", "Garcia");
Persona persona2 = persona1;
persona2.setNombre("Pedro");
System.out.println(persona1.getNombre());
```

El sistema tendrá esta salida:

```
Pedro
```

No es diferente cuándo haces una asignación entre elementos de un arreglo, que como las variables individuales, también almacenan referencias a los objetos.

```
Persona arreglo1[] = new Persona[2];
Persona arreglo2[] = new Persona[2];
arreglo1[0] = new Persona("Fran", "Garcia");
arreglo1[1] = new Persona("Juan", "Pérez");
arreglo2[0] = arreglo1[1];
arreglo2[1] = arreglo1[0];

arreglo1[1].setNombre("José");

System.out.println(arreglo1[1].getNombre());
System.out.println(arreglo2[0].getNombre());
```

Mostrará en la consola:

```
José
José
```

El hecho de usar la clase `Arrays` para realizar la copia de un arreglo a otro no cambia este hecho básico y elemental del lenguaje.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Los tipos de datos primitivos en java son: int, byte, short, long, float, double, boolean and char. Las variables de estos tipos si contienen el valor en si y no una referencia. Cuándo se asignan entre ellas, se crea una copia del valor.

**Edición:** Edité la respuesta, a sugerencia de Marce Puente, para agregar mayor claridad en cuanto a que son las variables de instancia de objetos las que contienen referencias y no las de tipos de datos primitivos.

Comment: Hola maestro!!, deberías aclarar que esto solo es cierto con los objetos, las variables que contienen primitivos se pasan por valor, no por referencia.

Comment: Buena sugerencia, había tratado de expresarme correctamente desde el inicio, pero la edité siguiendo tu sugerencia,espero haberme expresado más claramente ahora. Un saludo.

Comment: Maestro... inmejorable!!